# Read specific portions of an excel file based on string values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, strcmp, xlsread

I have an excel file and I need to read it based on string values in the 4th column. I have written the following but it does not work properly:

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('Coordinates','Centerville');

zn={};
ctr=0;
for i = 3:size(raw,1)
    tf = strcmp(char(raw{i,4}),char(raw{i-1,4}));
    if tf == 0
        ctr = ctr+1;
    end
    zn{ctr}=raw{i,4};
end

data=zeros(1,10); % 10 corresponds to the number of columns I want to read (herein, columns 'J' to 'S')
ctr=0;
for j = 1:length(zn)
    for i=3:size(raw,1)
        tf=strcmp(char(raw{i,4}),char(zn{j}));
        if tf==1
            ctr=ctr+1;
            data(ctr,:,j)=num(i-2,10:19);
        end
    end
end
```

It gives me a "15129x10x22 double" thing and when I try to open it I get the message "Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements". It might be obvious but what I am trying to get as the output is 'N = length(zn)' number of matrices which represent the data for different strings in the 4th column (so I probably need a struct; I just don't know how to make it work). Any ideas on how I could fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not test it, but this should help you get going:

**EDIT:** corrected wrong indexing into raw vector. Also, depending on the format you might want to restrict also the rows of the raw matrix. From your question, I assume something like `selector = raw(3:end,4);` and `data = raw(3:end,10:19);` should be correct.

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('Coordinates','Centerville');

selector = raw(:,4);
data     = raw(:,10:19);

[selector,~,grpidx] = unique(selector);

nGrp = numel(selector);

out  = cell(nGrp,1);
for i=1:nGrp
    idx      = grpidx==i;
    out{i}   = cell2mat(data(idx,:));
end
```

`out` is the output variable. The key here is the variable `grpidx` that is an output of the `unique` function and allows you to trace back the unique values to their position in the original vector. Note that `unique` as I used it may change the order of the string values. If that is an issue for you, use the `setOrder`parameter of the `unique` function and set it to `'stable'`